# Isomorphic fetch not working for external requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

EDIT: I'm actually looking to understand why the response does not contain the data I requested and whether it's due to certain libraries missing or the format of my fetchUrl variable

Hi I'm trying to use the isomorphic fetch method of making ajax requests and am struggling to get data from an external API.

Shouldn't this work and if not what am I missing?

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');          

router.get('/weather', function(req, res){
          var fetchUrl = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/xyz-token/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json';
          fetch(fetchUrl, {
            method: "GET"
          })
            .then(function(response){
              if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error("Bad request response from server");
              }
              console.log(response);
              res.send(response);
            });

        });
```

My response looks something like:

> {"url":"http://api.wunderground.com/api/xyz-token/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json","status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"_headers":{"server":["Apache/2.2.15
>   (CentOS)"],"access-control-allow-origin":["*"],"access-control-allow-credentials":["true"],"x-creationtime":["0.140"],"content-encoding":["gzip"],"last-modified":["Tue,
>   03 May 2016 10:47:33 GMT"],"content-type":["application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8"],"content-length":["1043"],"vary":["Accept-Encoding"],"expires":["Tue,
>   03 May 2016 10:48:58 GMT"],"cache-control":["max-age=0,
>   no-cache"],"pragma":["no-cache"],"date":["Tue, 03 May 2016 10:48:58
>   GMT"],"connection":["close"]}},"ok":true,"body":{"_opts":{},"_chunkSize":16384,"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":[],"length":0,"pipes":null,"pipesCount":0,"flowing":null,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":false,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","ranOut":false,"awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"domain":null,"_events":{"end":[null,null]},"_eventsCount":7,"_writableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"decodeStrings":true,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":1043,"writing":true,"corked":0,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writelen":1043,"bufferedRequest":null,"lastBufferedRequest":null,"pendingcb":1,"prefinished":false,"errorEmitted":false},"writable":true,"allowHalfOpen":true,"_transformState":{"needTransform":false,"transforming":true,"writechunk":{"type":"Buffer","data":[31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,165,86,91,143,218,56,20,126,158,249,21,86,164,149,90,9,114,5,2,72,85,133,102,52,218,213,118,232,106,41,157,125,139,60,142,19,44,146,56,107,59,195,208,138,255,190,199,137,67,194,165,157,74,203,11,248,251,206,205,159,15,199,190,253,126,139,144,37,168,44,121,33,169,53,71,245,250,133,10,201,120,97,205,45,215,246,172,129,134,20,21,185,228,201,138,138,23,70,192,208,218,40,85,206,29,103,183,219,217,187,170,136,169,72,5,135,111,155,240,220,217,81,172,54,84,56,184,100,78,236,212,174,246,70,229,89,19,42,1,182,130,148,109,54,194,139,152,41,200,167,17,15,144,195,237,205,1,190,6,55,22,169,132,160,133,138,248,179,132,196,88,213,69,129,215,205,141,197,114,156,210,118,81,137,172,43,137,65,64,105,239,94,171,180,46,38,21,184,220,48,34,157,93,229,59,25,79,121,228,5,238,235,212,181,203,34,133,130,192,91,49,149,233,45,61,53,101,163,117,183,157,198,32,99,197,246,231,91,182,192,236,80,219,198,76,150,25,222,71,25,39,39,245,38,85,166,107,92,225,2,61,8,92,16,38,9,31,160,187,69,147,129,48,181,63,103,27,70,42,172,116,113,173,101,189,142,10,156,215,32,206,88,194,69,193,176,9,3,245,40,161,35,173,87,....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Response` is a complex object, which contains not only the payload, but a lot of metadata, such as http status and headers.

In order to extract actual data, You might want to call one of the following methods:

```
response.json() // if the response contains json data
```

or

```
response.text() // if there is a plain text
```

You could investigate further on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

**Update.** Take into consideration that both methods return a Promise, so you could integrate them into the promise chain:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/weather', function(req, res){
  var fetchUrl = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/xyz-token/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json';
  fetch(fetchUrl)
    .then(function(response){
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad request response from server");
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {
      console.log(json);
      res.json(json);
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Yes tried this already and it returned nothing useful (not currently at my work machine so can't give example)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't seem to find the problem still. My response takes the form of the above, where there doesn't seem to be anything I wanted inside it, whether I convert to json or extract the text. Am I supposed to be using any other libraries (I'm not using babel or any other es6 libraries here) Do you have a working example I can compare to?

Comment: I guess in my haste my original question is a bit misleading

Comment: Found a solution below but don't really understand why it works

Comment: @darkace I've updated an example to the full source so you can check if it is working for you. I got node version 5.9.0 and lates express from npm. Can your log what `response.json()` returns?

Answer (score 1):

So I think I've figured out my problem.

I needed to handle the response object properly, but I don't understand the right way to do this.

I'm requesting a json object but can't use response.json() to get the data?

What worked:

```
      ...
      return response.text();

    }).then(function(body) {
      res.send(body);
      ...
```

I don't even understand why this is. Surely the response object is just an object that I can drill into like any other? What's the difference?